# Express req.body returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a form with a dynamic amount of input fields so I need to create a unique id for each one.  When I post the other inputs (the ones without unique id's), their values come back fine.  But all the inputs with the unique id's return undefined.  Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the relevant `server.js` code:

```
app.get('/creategroup', (request, response) => {
    var members = [];
    var memberCount = 5;
    for(var i = 1; i <= memberCount; i++){
        name_id = randomString(32, '#aA');
        phone_id = randomString(32, '#aA');
        var member = { 
          id: i,
          name: '',
          name_id: name_id,
          phone: '',
          phone_id: phone_id
        }
        members[i-1] = member;
      }
      app.locals.memberCount = members.length;
      app.locals.members = members;
      console.log("members: "+app.locals.memberCount+" : "+app.locals.members);
    response.render('creategroup', {
      memberCount: memberCount,
      members: members
    })
})
app.post('/creategroup', function(req, res) {
  res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  var group_name = req.body.group_name;
  var date = req.body.date;
  var price = req.body.price;
  var members = app.locals.members;
  var memberCount = app.locals.memberCount;
  console.log("count: "+memberCount);
  for (var i = 1; i <= members.length; i++) {
    member = members[i-1];
    name_id = member["name_id"];
    phone_id = member["phone_id"];
    console.log("name: "+name_id);
    console.log("phone: "+phone_id);
    console.log("Member "+i+": "+req.body.name_id+" : "+req.body.phone_id);
  }
})
```

Here is the relevant html for these input fields:

```
<div class="inputWrapper">
        <h2 class="title">Add group members</h2>
        {{#each members}}
        <div class="personWrapper">
            <div class="personItem">
                <label for={{id}}>Name</label>
                <input class="nameInput" id={{id}} name={{name_id}} type="text" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="personItem">
                <label for={{id}}>Phone Number</label>
                <input id={{id}} type="text" name={{phone_id}} placeholder="Phone number">
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
        <p id="addMembers" class="addPeople">Add more people</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're sure you're templating engine inserts quotes, and that it shouldn't be `id="{{id}}"` etc.

Comment: @adeneo yeah I'm pretty sure handlebars inserts quote. If I put quotes around the brackets wouldn't it make the id just the brackets with the word id in them?

Comment: If you're using Handlebars, it does **not** generally insert quotes in attributes, and it should be like in my comment above.

Comment: @NickEmmons are you using body-parser module?